# Where does mplayer store cache?

Tags: mplayer

I tried to look for this searching around but was unable to find it.  So I ask here instead of RTFS.

And how do you change the setting?

Comment: What do you mean by cache? Cache for what?

Comment: Try to write `mplayer -cache 8192` and it will buffer 8M.  Somewhere.

Comment: Probably somewhere in `~/.cache`.

Answer (score 4):

It's cached into RAM.

Fairly easy to test if you just use an absurdly high cache number. As long as you have enough RAM, you'll see an mplayer instance with super high RAM usage.

```
$ ps aux | awk 'NR==1 || $11~/^mplayer/'
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
oli       5869 21.5  0.5 1922224 147852 pts/5  Sl+  09:26   0:08 mplayer -cache 800000 ...
oli       5871  2.6  2.9 1163820 736484 pts/5  S+   09:26   0:00 mplayer -cache 800000 ...
```

Comment: Arguably, it should be called "buffering" then. It doesn't use a caching mechanism such as a browser does.